# Элемент неверно изменяет свою ширину

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Я бы хотел создать карточку (используя Bootstrap) с такими правилами:

1. карточка имеет минимальную ширину 250px (карточка #1 - корректно отображается)
2. если первая строка длиннее 250px, то карточка должна увеличить свою ширину, строка не должна оборачиваться (карточка #2 - ширина недостаточно увеличивается, строка оборачивается)
3. если левая и правая часть второй строки длиннее 250px, то карточка должна увеличить свою ширину, строки не должна оборачиваться (карточка #3 - ширина не увеличивается, строки оборачивается)
4. третья строка всегда оборачивается и не должна увеличивать ширину карточки (карточка #4 - ширина увеличивается)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На экране смартфона карточки так же отображаются некорректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему мой код не работает корректно?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-black m-2 p-2" style="min-width:250px;">
        <div class="">#1 Short string</div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><div>Left</div><div>Right</div></div>
        <div class="text-wrap">Short wrapped string</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-black m-2 p-2" style="min-width:250px;">
        <div class="">#2 Very very very very very very very very long string</div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><div>Left</div><div>Right</div></div>
        <div class="text-wrap">Short wrapped string</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-black m-2 p-2" style="min-width:250px;">
        <div class="">#3 Short string</div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><div>Left left left left</div><div>Right right right right</div></div>
        <div class="text-wrap">Short wrapped string</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-black m-2 p-2" style="min-width:250px;">
        <div class="">#4 Short string</div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><div>Left</div><div>Right</div></div>
        <div class="text-wrap">Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long wrapped string</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну начать наверное стоит с того, что у вас тут зачем-то стоят `<div class="w-100">`, которые имеют ширину 100% и тем самым мешают карточкам увеличивать свою ширину. Зачем они тут стоят?

Comment: @andreymal а вы бы сами попробовали запустить пример без этого дива и посмотрели что происходит.

Comment: Я запускал, без него всё намного лучше, первые три карточки начинают вести себя точно как вы хотите

Comment: @andreymal вот только мой вопрос не в том как заставить первые 3 отображаться, а все.